# Join MS Windows domain - "The user name or password is incorrect"

Tags: active-directory, domain, windows-server-2022

I am trying to join a Windows 2022 server to a AD domain running on another Windows 2022 server. I have tried several admin accounts including a domain account I created myself with - I think - necessary permissions.

After I provide credentials to join, Windows reports: "The user name or password is incorrect"

I tried all kinds of variations for the account name. The correct way I think is to use account@example.com but that and many other variations don't work. The message is always the same: "The user name or password is incorrect"

Of course I know the username and password is correct because I can use it for example to RDP into the machine.

It this is known issue? Is there a way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you trying to create a secondary domain server or join the machine as a client in the domain itself?

Comment: Have you tried domain/username as the format? I don't know specifically, but while username@domain does work for login, the more traditional domain/username is what I've used for authenticating for a Run As prompt.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was that in my local development environment AD was listening on two addresses: 10.0.2.15 and 1.1.8.108. After configuring 1.1.8.108 as the only address it started working. 

The problem as I understand it is that the AD DNS server was auto creating DNS records for 10.0.2.15 and this was causing for example nslookup from the node that was joining to fail.